# What is a "Band Switching Diode"?

Tags: rf, diodes

I have been coming across so-called "band switching diodes" recently, but I can't figure out what they actually are. Is this some type of RF switching PIN diode?

I came across these while I was searching for a cheap alternative to step recovery diodes. Someone recommended using the BA682, which is a band switching diode.

[BA682 link](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/data%20sheets/vishay%20semiconductors/ba682_83.pdf)

Comment: Have you had a look at that datasheet and the "typical applications"?

Comment: https://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9101024.pdf

Comment: Yeah, it says "band switching". So is it a PIN diode then? Why do I keep finding them listed as Standard diodes on Digikey?

Comment: @ColinMarcus: Its not a pin diode, it would say so. It is just a standard switching diode like 1n4148 or 1n914 or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planar silicon diode, specified for this application (dynamic resistance) and made with particularly low capacitance (and relatively high forward drop) compared to a jellybean switching diode.